# Verificar as respostas certas nas checkbox

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer que a menssagem window.alert('A certou') só aparecer quando as três checkbox com o name="certo" forem marcadas.

HTML5

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="resposta" name="certo">
<label>Abrir portas para um futro promissor.</label><br>

<input type="checkbox"  class="resposta" >
<label>Ganhar dinheiro.</label><br>

<input type="checkbox"  class="resposta" name="certo">
<label>Expandir minha rede de contatos profissional.</label><br>

<input type="checkbox"  class="resposta">
<label>Diminuir o desmatamento.</label><br>

<input type="checkbox"  class="resposta" name="certo">
<label>Promover meu trabalho.</label><br>

<input type="button"  value="Verificar" onclick="verificar()">
```

Javascript

```
function verificar(){
    let resposta = document.querySelector('.resposta')
    let correto = document.getElementsByName('certo')

    for (var marcado in resposta) {
        if(resposta[marcado].checked){
            window.alert('Marcada')
            if(correto == true){
               return window.alert('A certou')
            }else{
                return window.alert('Errou')
            }
        }
        else
        return window.alert('Em branco')
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vc pode criar uma função que percorra os input certos e so retorne verdadeiro se todos tiverem checados. assim:

```
    function verificar() {
        console.log(verificarCheckbox())
        if (verificarCheckbox()) {
            alert("Acertou")
        } else {
            alert("Errou")
        }
    }

    function verificarCheckbox() {
        let correto = document.getElementsByName('certo')
        let isValid = true
        correto.forEach(function (el) {
            if (!el.checked) {
                isValid = false
            }
        })
        return isValid
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado hiago-buzz, nem tinha pensado em fazer uma function separada para percorra os input certos. :)